# Monitor a command and wait for it to complete before proceeding to next command?

Tags: powershell

I have written a PowerShell script that will:

1. grab all txt files from a directory
2. perform a line-by-line assessment of the first file (grabbing headers and appending, appending data to each line in file, saving to an output file)
3. for subsequent files, grab body (excluding header), append data, then add to output file

The problem is in the use of `Add-Content` where the process hangs so certain files don't get written because the output file is in use. I added a function (based on recommendations found in various places on StackExchange) that test the output file to determine if it is available for read-write. This seems like a 'brute-force' approach.

Is there a way to monitor the actual `Add-Content` process launched by PowerShell to identify when it is complete? Or is there some other way to disaggregate the code as written to use the process control commands in PowerShell?

Sample:

```
function IsFileAccessible([String]$FullFileName) {
    [Boolean]$IsAccessible = $false

    try {
        [IO.File]::OpenWrite($FullFileName).Close();
        $IsAccessible = $true
    } catch {
        $IsAccessible = $false
    }

    return $IsAccessible
}

cd '[filepath]'
del old_output.type
$filearray = @()

$files = Get-ChildItem '[filepath]' -Filter "*.txt"
$outfile = 'new_output.type'

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    # Define variables
    $lastWriteTime = $files[$i].LastWriteTime

    # Define process steps for appending data    
    filter Add-Time {"$_$lastWriteTime"}

    if ($i -eq 0) {
        $lines = Get-Content $files[$i]
        for ($j=0;$j -lt $lines.Count; $j++) {
            if ($j -eq 0) {
                $appended_txt = 'New_Header'
                filter Add-Header{"$_$appended_txt"}
                $lines[$j] | Add-Header | Add-Content $outfile
            } else {
                $lines[$j] | Add-Time | Add-Content $outfile
            }
        }
    } else {
        do {
            $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
            $test = IsFileAccessible('[filepath-new_output.type]')
            echo 'file open'
        } until ($test -eq 'True')

        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
        echo 'okay'
        (Get-Content $files[$i].FullName | Select-Object -Skip 1) |
            Add-Time | Add-Content $outfile
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAICS there's no concurrency in the code you posted.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Any error messages that might help us?

Comment: @JamesC based off 'The problem is...the process hangs so certain files don't get written', I'm assuming no error, just hanging execution.